# how to display image writing an html code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvQlt.png)where am i going wrong. i want to view output the stack overflow image.

`from Ipython.core.display import HTML, display`

`display(HTML('<img src= stackoverflow.jpg alt= stackoverflow.com width=104 height=142>'))`

Result is a broken image icon

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the syntax of HTML is like this:

```
<img src="stackoverflow.jpg" alt="stackoverflow.com" width=104 height=142>
```

Note the minor difference between your version and this one.

Comment: I tried that but i get a syntax error. I am running this on jupyter notebook. See below for the error:     File "<ipython-input-6-7b0611e280c2>", line 1
    <img src="stackoverflow.jpg" alt="stackoverflow.com" width=104 height=142>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it's hard to say what went wrong, one possible issue is the mixed use of single quotes and double quotes. How about this `display(HTML('<img src="stackoverflow.jpg" alt="stackoverflow.com" width=104 height=142>'))`

Comment: I tried that and still no luck. it is giving the same error.

Comment: perhaps you misspelled `Ipython`, it should be `IPython` instead.

Comment: i didn't make an error there so i don't know where i went wrong. Thank you Kong for your input